# How To Access underlaying xml values

Tags: c#, xml

I am using the following to pass information to a save function.

```
  List<XElement> listElements = new List<XElement>();

   listElements.Addnew XElement(@"TextBox", new XElement("name"),
                             new XElement("Type", "System.String"),
                               new XElement("displayName", ""),
                               new XElement("length", "12"),
                                new XElement("key", false),
                                new XElement("required", false)));

  listElements.Add(new XElement(@"ClassficationEnum", new XElement("name","TestForm"),
                             new XElement("Type", "System.String"),
                               new XElement("displayName", "TestForm"),
                               new XElement("length", "12"),
                                new XElement("key", false),
                                new XElement("required", false)));
```

I am then passing it to the update command as follows

```
      portalContext.UpdateFormBuilder(formToUpdate, strName.ToString(), listElements.ToString());
```

And to Save to my entity I am using this

```
            var q = from forms in portalEntities.FormBuilders
                    where forms.Name == formName                        
                    select forms;


            List<FormBuilder> formBuilderRecords = q.ToList();
            foreach (FormBuilder formsBuilder in formBuilderRecords)
            {
                formsBuilder.Name = formName;
                formsBuilder.ExtraFields = xml.ToString();
                formsBuilder.title = Title;



            }


            return SaveChanges();
```

Problem I am having is that its just saving the following to the database how can i get all the values instead of just this out.

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.ToString()` on `XElement` to get it's XML markup, but calling `.ToString()` on `List` will only print it's type. So your problem isn't about getting underlying XML value but saving the XML value correctly.

If you meant to save all those `XElement`s as single XML in database you need to put them within single root element :

```
.....
var root = new XElement("root", listElements);
.....
portalContext.UpdateFormBuilder(formToUpdate, strName.ToString(), root.ToString());
```